# Cite a webpage in Lyx using Mendeley

Tags: bibtex, lyx

I would like to cite a webpage. Citations are collected in Mendeley 1.17.13 which has BibTex syncing enabled. The citation is inserted into Lyx 2.2.3. with citation style natbib author-year, bibliography style plain, bibliography generator default, BibTex Generated Bibliography style set to apa.

LibreOffice using the Mendeley plug in, produces the right result:

> CIF. (2018). What We Do | Climate Investment Funds. Retrieved February 1, 2018, from https://www.climateinvestmentfunds.org/about

Lyx doesn't:

> CIF (2018). What We Do | Climate Investment Funds.

How can I add the missing "Retrieved" and "from" fields?

A small Tex file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5a8sdgawn4m900c/newfile2.tex?dl=0).

Comment: If LyX literally uses the `apa.bst` to implement the APA style, it's a very old and poor approximation of APA. To get proper APA style you need to either us `biblatex` with `[style=apa]` or the `apacite` package with the `[natbibapa]` option `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`. Since I don't use LyX I can't help you on how to do that, though.

Comment: LyX supports apa6.

Comment: I have tried apacite, apacitex, apalike and chicago. None of them produce links and date assessed in the biography.

Comment: @scottkosty `apa6` is a document class that has nothing to do with bibliographies.

Comment: @Henk `apacite` should do the right thing, I think. Can you make a small sample document and export the TeX and add it to your question?

Comment: @AlanMunn oops, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @AlanMunn I have added a link to a sample file.

Comment: The `apacite` bibliography style must be used in conjunction with the `apacite` package, which must be passed the option `natbibapa` if it is used with `natbib`.  So you need to edit your preamble to add `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}`.  See [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793)

Comment: Added - doesn't compile with lots of "Undefined control sequence."

Comment: Works with "apa" if I change document class to "APA". But in my original document this generates errors ("LaTeX Error: No \long \def \GenericError {   }{LaTex Error: No \t"). When selecting "show output anyway" the references contain links for _every_ entry, not just the webpages.

Comment: Found the solution: in Lyx /Document/Settings/Modules you have to activate Natbibapa. Doing this in the preamble does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Henk, you may try these steps:

1. In your Mendeley, activate the 'Medium' field for webpage entries in the tool options: (Tools > Options > Document Details)
2. Then, put the retrieve date and webpage’s url in the medium-field: e.g. Retrieved February 1, 2018, from https://www.climateinvestmentfunds.org/about
3. Finally, export your Bibtex file and render the document.

Ref: http://www.bar54.de/2013/10/mendeley-webpage-entry-urls-in-bibtex-export/